# creating an array from a list of space separated integers

Tags: java, arrays, list, integer

I am trying to make a java program which can accept a list of numbers, each separated by a whitespace (Ex: 1 2 3 5 69 3124124 etc...) which then puts these numbers into an array and checks for duplicates. The whole thing works fine except for this method which is giving me trouble:

```
public static List returnArray(){
System.out.println("type numbers here: ");
    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
        list.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    return list;
```

"sc" is the arraylist

It works fine except the only way for the program to understand it's finished being given input is for me to add a letter or something to the end, so an input of 1 2 3 doesn't do anything but an input of 1 2 3 r results in [1 2 3]. Any ideas how to write this so that it will know to stop taking input after more than one blank space and not need some other character at the end?

Comment: I assume you mean sc is the scanner? It appears as though `list` is your arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan in a whole line (ONLY ONE LINE) first using `scan.readLine()`, and parse THAT string instead.

Basically, read a line (as a string), and split it up using spaces (split(" ") function), then for each one, parse it into an integer and add it to the arraylist list. Return list at the end.

```
eg:
public static List returnArray() {
    System.out.println("Type numbers here: ");
    String input = sc.readLine();
    String[] x = input.split(" ");
    for (String y : x) {
        Int tempInt = Integer.parseInt(y);
        list.add(tempInt);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that it has to be able to read from multiple lines

Comment: What do you want it to do exactly? Enter 1 line, return an array, then enter another one? or enter them all at the beginning, then return one big array? or enter them all at the beginning and return a bunch of small arrays?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a BufferedReader which is faster than the Scanner.
It goes like this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine()); //throws IOException
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
     list.add(Integer.valueOf(tokenizer.nextToken()));
}
```

Comment: The use of `StringTokenizer` is discouraged in new code. It only still exists to support legacy code.

Comment: it tells me I can't use a bufferedreader with the default constructor

Comment: @AdamP Oh I see, but I've always been told that this is the faster way, because once I was on a competition which needed programs that answer under 0.1 millisec and with java you could only earn points by using StringTokenizer.

Comment: @MikeHawk Make sure, that you define BufferedReader with this:         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Comment: @AdamP No matter what I do I get this error preventing the program from running: Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: Yeah, so you've got this in a method right? After public static List returnArray() write throws IOException. So after it looks like this: public static Listt returnArray() throws IOException {}. And for further read http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076700/core-java/exceptions-in-java.html or just google "Java exceptions".